# Retrieving Value from Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I encounter this problem. What I want to do is, I want to retrieve the value of the datepicker and store it in the variable, then I wanted the value to popup. However, when I click Go button , I got the undefined as the value.Here's my code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true});
  });
  </script>
  <style>
    div.ui-datepicker{font-size:10px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<input value="  Go  " onClick="Go_OnClick()" type="button">

<script>
    function Go_OnClick(){
        dateVariable = $("datepicker").val();
        alert(dateVariable);
    }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: dateVariable = $("#datepicker").val();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing # when we are trying to get the val of datepicker.

So use $("#datepicker").val(); in Go_OnClick() methos and it will work

Answer (score 2):

You missed `#` for IDselector, and that might not be good practice to retrieve date with using `.val()` you'll get string value, to retrieve date:

You need to use [`getDate()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate)

```
function Go_OnClick(){
    dateVariable = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate'); //getDate and # for ID selectror
    alert(dateVariable);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.

Change `dateVariable = $("datepicker").val();` to  `dateVariable = $("#datepicker").val();`

You were missing one # before `datepicker`